# Order By Clause return wrong order when there are special characters in record set

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I am using SQL server. I am fetching student information from database. I order by lastname and then first name like `ORDER BY lastname, firstname` it works until I have simple data. Issue occurs when there is '~' or any other character in name occur. It disturb order.

**UPDATE**
Here is what I am getting currently

[image: Currently]

and on front end I have this

[image: Front End]

Expectation is 2 and 3 should be after 4 and 5 as k comes first order then ñ

Comment: Where do you think should `~` sort in your collation?

Comment: Would you care to provide some sample data, and then describe what order you *expected* the data to appear in, and the "wrong" order that is produced. Please [edit] your question to provide such details.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Question edited with current result and expected result.

Comment: Eh? The data that you're showing appears to contain `Ã`, not `ñ`. It doesn't seem unreasonable that `Ã` sorts before `k`.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever See Image in updated question please.

Comment: So, the actual issue is that you're corrupting your data when you insert it but somehow expecting SQL Server to perform sorting as if the data wasn't corrupted?

Comment: Yes you got it right.

Comment: You're misusing SQL Server's data types. You're apparently storing UTF 8 data into a `varchar` (which expects some variant of "ASCII" data). You should instead switch to using `nvarchar` for those columns. Then SQL Server can "see" the real data.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Currently I am not able to change data type. Could you please guide me how to fix issue with out changing data type.

Comment: You can do the sorting in the front-end after it has unmangled the data. But that won't help if you're also trying to do e.g. paging in the server. SQL Server just really doesn't understand UTF8 so it has no mechanism to convert to UTF16 which is what it's designed to work with. Personally, I'd be more concerned about whether all UTF8 strings can be round-tripped through a varchar *at all*. I.e. it appears with your *current* set of data that your front-end can unmangle the data, but are you sure it will be able to in all circumstances? Are you sure fixing the data types is off the table?

Answer (score 1):

Use `Collate` with your query. Hope that can help! Like:

```
SELECT FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME
FROM TABLE
ORDER BY FIRSTNAME Collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1253_CI_AI
```

Comment: Confirmed - "ñ" is sorted differently by "Latin1_General_BIN" compared to "Modern_Spanish_CI_AS" for example

Comment: The problem is, the column doesn't contain `ñ`. It contains `Ã±` because someone's storing UTF-8 encoded data into a `varchar` column.

Answer (score 0):

Make this function in sql server-----

```
    CREATE FUNCTION dbo.RemoveSpecialChars (@s VARCHAR(256))
RETURNS VARCHAR(256)
    WITH schemabinding

BEGIN
    IF @s IS NULL
        RETURN NULL

    DECLARE @s2 VARCHAR(256)

    SET @s2 = ''

    DECLARE @l INT

    SET @l = len(@s)

    DECLARE @p INT

    SET @p = 1

    WHILE @p <= @l
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @c INT

        SET @c = ascii(substring(@s, @p, 1))

        IF @c BETWEEN 48
                AND 57
            OR @c BETWEEN 65
                AND 90
            OR @c BETWEEN 97
                AND 122
            SET @s2 = @s2 + CHAR(@c)
        SET @p = @p + 1
    END

    IF len(@s2) = 0
        RETURN NULL

    RETURN @s2
END
```

now you can order by like ---

```
SELECT *
FROM yourtablename
ORDER BY dbo.RemoveSpecialChars(yourcolumnname)
```

Comment: Will this remove "ñ" from name and then order by?

Comment: yes this will remove your special character from name then order by.but your return result have this special character .

Comment: Goal is not to remove special characters